# Как удалить все что после символа "+" в строке

Tags: символы, javascript

Имеется ссылка вида http://www.сайт.ру/страница/подстраница_1+строка
как удалить "+строка" с помощью JS

Comment: Ну раз уж такая пьяна, то самый быстрый способ - это с использованием substr, опережает двух других примерно в два раза. Тестил при 100000 операциях.

Comment: @lampa заинтересовало такое заявление ))) решил сам потестить... Пришел к выводу что все результаты дают нестабильное время, но регулярка определенно оказывалась в пролете...:

**split** выиграл в 40%

**substr** выиграл в 40%

**replace** выиграл в 20%

Comment: @IVsevolod видимо браузеры разные) Я проверяю простым циклом, см: https://github.com/lampaa/JSTF

Answer (score 6):

Можно вот так:

```
var s = 'http://www.сайт.ру/страница/подстраница_1+строка';
s = s.split('+')[0];
```

---

**А вот мои тесты, выполнялись в консоли Хрома.**

[Вот исходники теста](http://jsfiddle.net/m9AjC/)

[image: скрин тестов с консоли]

Answer (score 4):

Или так:

```
var s = 'http://www.сайт.ру/страница/подстраница_1+строка';
s.substr(0,s.indexOf("+"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Ну или так:

```
var s = 'http://www.сайт.ру/страница/подстраница_1+строка'.replace(/\+.*/, '');
```